# Where i can take free RPM Apache Ambari?

Tags: hadoop

I search for Ambari for Centos. But on Apache site there is only source code.
I found several links on public-repo.hortonworks, but can't find this repository in index, and latest version is 2.7.4. On Apache site the latest is 2.7.5.

Comment: Apache Ambari is open source project, you can find all versions on github https://github.com/apache/ambari

Comment: i try assembly from site Ambari.apache, not github. And build was failed. Some problems on amabari-admin when front building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.7.5 repos are now behind a paywall @Cloudera.  If you want 2.7.5 you need to build from source.  My best recommendation is to use 2.7.4 and public repos as there is not much of a difference.

Comment: Yes, for now it is not problem. Little difference in minor version. But project live, what doing when relese version 2.8 for example?
Cloudera have comminity edition? I watch they site. And not seem free distributives.

Comment: @DmitryKa your two choices are to build from source or get a cloudera license.   Cloudera will only be updating Ambari for a short time.  The current updates to HDP are only to support migrating to CDP or CDC or CD(X).

Comment: @steven-matison can you give a full instruction page for building ambari 2.7.4 including prerequisites?